# Proper way to store permissions (datatype)

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I'm modeling a MySQL database and it has a `users` table with the columns:

- username
- passhash
- permissions

The access crontrol will be made on programming level (NodeJS).

Each user may have a different combination of permissions to modules M#.

One user may have permissions to access M1, M2, and M3.
another user may have permissions to access M2 and M4, and so on...

I would like to know what is the best way to store that kind of information.

I read a long time ago about the binary thing like:

`000010001` - permitted access to M0 and M4

`010000100` - permitted access to M2 and M7

`000000011` - permitted access to M0 and M1

I am confused on how to store and retrieve that information. What datatype would be suitable for that purpose?

Comment: Sounds like you might use the [`BIT` data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html)

Comment: Or SET or INT (and use boolean operators)

Comment: It would be nice if you guys could show an example.